# How to download the entire page with wget when the url has parameters?

Tags: html, wget

I want to download the entire page with all its objects, including images, js, css, etc. However, the url may contain parameters, eg.

> www.youtube.com/results?search_query=star+wars

I have tried the options suggested in similar questions:

```
wget -p -k "www.youtube.com/results?search_query=star+wars"
wget -p -k ‐‐post-data "search_query=star+wars" "https://www.youtube.com/results"
```

But none of them works. Can anybody help me with that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off $URL
```

NOTE: The URL must be quoted by ''.

REF: https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget